# pass variable values as arguments to a python function

Tags: python

I am trying pass variable values as arguments to a function which I am calling with in a for loop. Somehow before calling the function when I print the variable values they are showing fine but they are not getting passed into function as I am getting Index out of range :0 which means nothing is passed. Researched with no use...your help is really appreciated.
Code is:

```
 for clx in root.findall('sample'):
        CName = clx.find('Name').text
        No01 = clx.find('First').text
        No02 = clx.find('Second').text
        print "Cname provided is" +CName
        print "First is" +No01
        print "Second is" +No02
        createCluster(CName, No01, No02)
```

createCluster:

```
def createCluster(CName, No01, No02):
    print len(sys.argv)
    ClsName=sys.argv[0]
    Node01=sys.argv[1]
    Node02=sys.argv[2]
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "createCluster.py", line 8, in createCluster
    ClsName=sys.argv[0]
IndexError: index out of range: 0
```

Comment: Is `createCluster` the method you are trying to call that is giving you that error? Please show the definition for that method. Show the full traceback of the error. Copy paste the error in to your question along with the method definition.

Comment: `sys.argv` is how parameters are passed to your program via the command line; it has NOTHING to do with parameters to any one function inside your program.  Those can be accessed simply by the names they were given in the `def` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not extracting the arguments passed to your method properly. In Python, you simply just use the arguments that you defined in your method like this:

```
def createCluster(CName, No01, No02):
    print(CName)
    print(No01)
    print(No02)

createCluster('a', 'b', 'c')
```

The above will output

```
a
b
c
```

For your issue on your usage of `sys.argv` that you are incorrectly using:

Snippet from the documentation on [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.

In example of this would be when calling your code from a shell prompt:

> python your_script.py a b c

Inside `your_script.py` you will ahve

```
import sys

script_name = sys.argve[0]
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]
arg3 = sys.argv[3]
```

Which will output:

```
/absolute/path/to/your_script.py
a
b
c
```

So, you see here that it ends up giving you the name of the script and all arguments.

This is maybe where your confusion came from between calling a script and calling the method in the script.

Comment: Thank you it worked. All I have to do remove those sys args.